# It is possible to create an A* admissible heuristic with zero cost path values?

Tags: path-finding, a-star

When we use A* with a non admissible heuristic we can sometimes get a non optimal path as result.

But when it is allowed to have path with zero cost, the only admissible heuristic that comes to my mind is `h(x) = 0`, which turns A* into a "simple" Dijkstra's algorithm.

Am I correct? Is this the only possible admissible heuristic? What is the real loss of not using an admissible heuristic? There is other path-finding algorithm that works better with zero cost paths?

---

An example:

Suppose the following graph (the numbers above edges shows the costs):

```
   1      1      0      1      1
S --> V1 --> V2 --> V3 --> V4 --> G
```

Where:

- S means **start vertex**
- V means **inner vertex**
- G means **goal vertex**

By looking the graph, we see that `C(S) = 4`.

What heuristic function `h(x)` can I use? If I use euclidian distance I got:

```
f(S) = g(S) + h(S)
f(S) = 0 + 5 = 5
```

We can see that this heuristic over-estimates the real distance, therefore for a more complex graph, it may not find the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not true.  The heuristic function `h(x)` has argument `x` consisting of the current search state. It returns an estimate of the distance from `x` to the goal. In a simple graph, `x` is a graph node.

Admissibility requires that `h(x)` can only be an *under-estimate* (or equal to the goal distance). This condition is for *each particular x*.  (You seem to be inferring the condition is for *all possible x*, which is far too strong. A* would be useless if this were necessary.)

The correct statement regarding the case you propose is that `h(x) = 0` is necessary *only* when `x` is a state with distance zero to the goal.  Any other value would be an over-estimate. However, for any other `x` (in the same state space) that requires transitions with total at least cost `C>0` to get to the goal, we can have any `h` such that `h(x)<=C`.

Of course if `x`'s distance to goal is zero, then `x` *is* the goal state and the search is complete.  So your concern is vacuous - there are no cases where it's of interest.

Information to construct `h(x)` comes from your knowledge of the search space (e.g. characteristics of the graph).  A bare, general graph alone doesn't provide anything useful.  The best you can do is `h(x) = cost of min weight outgoing edge of x` for non-goal nodes and, as already discussed, `h(x) = 0` for the goal.  Again note this is a lower bound on distance to goal.  It gives you Dijkstra!

To do better you need to know something about the graph's structure.

**Edit**

In your example, you are providing detailed knowledge, so making a good `h` is simple. You can use

```
        /  4   if x == S
       |   3   if x == V1 
h(x) = {   2   if x == V2 or V3 
       |   1   if x == V4
        \  0   if x == G
```

or you can use any other function `h'(x)` such that `h'(x) <= h(x)` for all `x`.  For example, this would be admissible:

```
         /  3   if x == S
        |   2   if x == V1 
h'(x) = {   2   if x == V2 or V3 
        |   1   if x == V4
         \  0   if x == G
```

**Addition**

The OP points out that for many problems, `h(x)` can be hard to choose!  This is precisely correct.  If you can't find a good admissible heuristic, then A* is the wrong algorithm!  Nonetheless, A* is very effective for problems where heuristics can be found.  Examples I've tried myself:

1. Graphs where Euclidean distance is a good lower bound on the possible distance between any two nodes. For example, each pair of cities A and B is separated by a distance D "as the crow flies," but the road distance from A to B is at least D in length and possibly much more, i.e. its cost C is greater than or equal to D.  In this case, D makes a fine heuristic because it's a low estimate.
2. Puzzles where "distance" to the winning state involves moving game pieces.  In this case, the number of pieces currently out of position with respect to the winning state is a fine heuristic.  Examples are the 8-bishop's problem from 7th Guest (number of bishops not yet in their final positions) and the Magic Square Problem (total Manhatten distance from all pieces' current positions to their correct position in the winning state).

Comment: [This link](http://heuristicswiki.wikispaces.com/Admissible+Heuristic) says an admissible heuristic is one that does not overestimate the actual distance. Maybe that is the point where I am getting confused.

Comment: Stand by.  I was confused.  Cannot overestimate is right.  You must under-estimate or be perfect. But the place where your reasoning comes off the rails is still correct.  You need `h(x)=0` only when `mindist(x, G) = 0`.

Comment: The heuristic function you suggested uses knowledge of vertices that have not yet been "visited". This approach is impractical when the graph has, for example, thousands of vertices. Being in the initial vertex S, how the heuristic function "guessed" there is a step with zero cost?

Comment: @borges All heuristics use knowledge of the search space.  That's exactly what a heuristic is: an encoding of this knowledge! If you can't find one, then A* is not a good algorithm, and certainly there are many problems where that's true.  I think you're still seeing this from the wrong point of view.  Try the addition to my post. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @borges Another way of explaining your example:  If you had knowledge that whenever an edge (a,b) of zero weight is seen, then the goal is at least cost 2 away (and maybe more), then you'd be safe to say `h(z)=2` for `z=a, z=b`.  You'd need more information to deal with other nodes `y \not\in {a,b}`.  Otherwise you'd have to say `h(y)=0` as you say.